# my funtion is not working when i copy paste it on input in my mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keydown, keyup

when i try to copy paste my text it's working in desktop browsr but when i open it on my mobile and copy and paste it won't show the text on  `<span id="addy"></span>` i have to at least press the input or retype something,

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

    <title>Skyverse | Mint</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="check" type="text">
    <span id="addy"></span>
    <script id="rendered-js" >
      $('input[type="text"]').on('keydown, keyup', function () {
        //get a reference to the text input value
        var texInputValue = $('#check').val();
      
        //show the text input value in the UI
        $('#addy').html(texInputValue);
      });
      //# sourceURL=pen.js
          </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the `input` event instead of `keydown` and `keyup`

Comment: `keyXXX` events are only triggered when you actually press a key.

Comment: can you please modify the code removing "keydown and keyup " i'm little bit new to jquery, that would be great

Comment: `'keydown keyup'` -> `'input'`